# PHP: Change dropdown style or appreance if dropdown option is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

Can you help me?.. I want my drop down change it's style if user selected any option either  make the dropdown selection object text turn to red or make the drop down itself turn to red color instead of default blue so user cannot confius , can notice the drop down is selected or changed and can differentiate if he miss any drop down. In my case user required to select all the drop down.

**My logic is** : if the dropdown not change or the value is other than 0 then -> show something to dropdown to make user notice the dropdown already change or rated

or if the user select any dropdown then change someting to dropdown appreance or style

**You can see my dropdown here :** https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ljW8PVjKQC4FMqFPU54uNbiuVqOmi6G-0JPCucinqME/pub

My dropdown code will loop based how many question in MySQL. If it have 2 question then the drpdown will show 2:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
    {   
         <td class='section2' id='self_assess_staff'>
              <select id='self_assess_staff' name='self_assess[]'>
                 <option value='0' selected>-</option>
                 <option value='1' width='2px'>1</option>
                 <option value='2'>2</option>
                 <option value='3'>3</option> 
                 <option value='4'>4</option>
                 <option value='5'>5</option>
             </select>
         </td>
    }
echo "    </tbody> 
                </div></div>
                <tr><td></td<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td align='right'><button id='EditSubmit1' onclick='checkbox();'>Submit Data</button></td></tr>
                </table>";  
            }
```

since you guys ask for my javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#EditSubmit1").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();     

            var self_assess_check = $("select[name='self_assess[]'] option:selected").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
            }).get();

            //alert(self_assess_check);

            if ($.inArray('-', self_assess_check) != -1) {
                alert("Please Make Sure All Question Have been rate");
                return false;
            } else {
                var r = confirm("Make sure all answer is correct. Once Submit it cannot be changed");
                if (r == true) {
                } else {
                return false;
                }
            } 

            var self_assess = $("select[name='self_assess[]'] option:selected").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
            }).get();

             alert(self_assess);

            var JsonData = {self_assess: self_assess,};  

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // Post Get method
            url: "answer_response.php", //Where form data is sent on submission
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:JsonData, //Form variables
            success:function(response){     

                $("#contentLeft").append(response);

            alert("Your Data Have Been Recorded");
                window.location.reload(true);   // reload after append  
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
            }); 
    });

            $("#CancelSubmit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            window.location.reload(true);                   
            });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. If you want to change style as the user selects things, that must be done in Javascript. If you want to set style when you're creating the original page, that's in PHP. Which are you trying to do? Your loop doesn't use `$row`, what is it doing with the database?

Comment: yes.. if user changed or select the dropdown.. i want the dropdown change too.. i want to make sure the user see which dropdown user not answer because the dropdown will loop maybe 10 or 20. so user can't differentiate if they miss one or two dropdown.

Comment: Then use Javascript to bind a handler to the `change` event that does what you want. Use CSS classes to change the styles of the dropdowns.

Comment: your code does not make any sense. your mysql is incomplete and does not contain any jquery as tagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VQRuS/2/)**

EDIT:

```
  $("#button1").on("click", function(){
    var flag=true;
    $("select").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="0")
            $(this).addClass("err");
    }).on("change", function(){
        if($(this).val()!="0")
            $(this).addClass("ok").removeClass("err");
        else
            $(this).addClass("err").removeClass("ok");
    });

});
```

create dynamic dropdown with php:

```
<select id='self_assess_staff' name='self_assess[]'>
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
{ 
   $selected = (a condition)? "selected=selected":""; //If it have 2 question     
   echo "<option ".$selected." value='".$row["value"]."'>".$row["value"]."</option>";
}
</select>
```

Comment: i think this is not what i want.. i just want user notice the dropdown change after clicked of change other than 0

Comment: so you can use jquery, see my EDIT

Comment: i have already the error massage.. what i need is when user change the dropdown.. it make something to the dropdown.. like the dropdown become red instead of blue to make sure user know which dropdown he not rated because if i have 1000 dropdown, they cant find which dropdown not rated yet

Comment: instead display an error message can u make the dropdown become red or something

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the user action to change style that you can get with the onchange event of the dropdown

```
<select id='self_assess_staff' name='self_assess[]' onchange="change_style();">
             <option value='0' selected>-</option>
             <option value='1' width='2px'>1</option>
             <option value='2'>2</option>
             <option value='3'>3</option> 
             <option value='4'>4</option>
             <option value='5'>5</option>
         </select>
```

Write javascript function

```
function change_style()
{
   //now with the id "self_assess_staff" you can change any style attribute of 0the dropdown
document.getElementById('self_assess_staff').style.attribute='whatever you want';//this is for changing an attiribute
document.getElementById('self_assess_staff').className='whatever you want';//this is to change the class name 
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on the class.. seem that only first dropdown change because the dropdown in array.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript and create an onchange action for your code

```
     <select id='self_assess_staff' name='self_assess[]' onchange='jsAction(this)'>
                 <option value='0' selected>-</option>
                 <option value='1' width='2px'>1</option>
                 <option value='2'>2</option>
                 <option value='3'>3</option> 
                 <option value='4'>4</option>
                 <option value='5'>5</option>
             </select>

    //js
    <script>
    function jsAction(val){
     alert(val.text);
    }
</script>
```

something like this

Comment: yes. something like this but i need more inside the function and where is the val come from?

Comment: its up to you on what kind of actions you want to do inside of the script.. that was just the basic idea..

Comment: i know the basic idea.. :P .. that why i ask this question..i need the function.. btw thanks